# Joomla module with ajax and jexec

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I've developed a login module using AJAX. One of the functionalities is username availability checking. Of course this makes use of an external PHP file, containing the line:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

This is causing all the trouble. And this line has to be in there. As you know AJAX cant call this file, access denied..

Some people say I have to make an component, but I prefer to avoid this.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the AJAX call to your own PHP file that has the line

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
```

Then get the information you need from the other PHP file.

I use XMLRPC to call files on remote Joomla machines, and the remote PHP files all have this line, which works fine. Note the difference between `define` and `defined`.

Comment: I folded the comment issue into my answer.  @MaartenHartman, could you delete your first comment so as to avoid confusion?